# Get specific information from wikipedia on google spreadsheet (not the entire table)

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula, wikipedia

I have a table from "Lead rolling actors" from Wikipedia and I want to add some columns to the table with the dates of birth, years active etc for every actor.

[Lead rolling actors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3WEH.png)

It's the first time I use IMPORTXML formula but for Robert Downey Jr I am trying the following:

-**Born**: =IMPORTXML(G1!,"//span[@class='bday']")

< span class="bday">1965-04-04</ span>

-**Years Active**: =IMPORTXML(G1!,"//td[@class='infobox-data']")

< td class="infobox-data">1970–present</ td>

In both cases it gives me errors. What am I doing wrong? I looked on https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheet-web-scraper/  to get some guidance but I can't find my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question and showing image, unfortunately, I cannot see the URL of `Robert Downey Jr`. But, if the URL is supposed as `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Downey_Jr`, I think that your xpath of `//span[@class='bday']` returns `1965-04-04`. But, your xpath of `//td[@class='infobox-data']` returns multiple values.

In this answer, the values of `1965-04-04` and `1970–present` are retrieved from the URL of `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Downey_Jr`.

#### Sample 1:

In this sample, `1965-04-04` is retrieved from `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Downey_Jr`.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Downey_Jr","//span[@class='bday']")
```

[image]

#### Sample 2:

In this sample, `1970–present` is retrieved from `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Downey_Jr`.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Downey_Jr","//td[@class='infobox-data' and ../th[contains(text(),'active')]]")
```

[image]

#### Note:

- Although I'm not sure about your current URL of `Robert Downey Jr`, for example, how about checking the URL again? Because when I use the URL of `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Downey_Jr`, your expected values could be retrieved.

Comment: Yes sorry the url is en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Downey_Jr. with dot at the end. 
<br>
I have seen it's because the formula uses the url and I was using the cell (G1 in this case) so I believe it is working now Thank you very much for the help. 
<br>
Just by curiosity, would there be any way to use the cell instead the url (G1, G2, G3, G4...)? In this case the list is short, but in case I have a broader list sometime

Comment: @Alberto Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `<br> Just by curiosity, would there be any way to use the cell instead the url (G1, G2, G3, G4...)? In this case the list is short, but in case I have a broader list sometime`, I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: Oh sorry my English it's not very good either. I have been "playing" with the formula and I think I find what I was looking for already. My question was basically if there was a formula like =IMPORTXML("G2","//span[@class='bday']"), but I have found =IMPORTXML(G2,"//span[@class='bday']") works so everything is fine now. Thank you very much for all the help Tanaike

Comment: @Alberto Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.